# Multiplying column in SQL Server based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to multiply a column in SQL Server based on a specific condition.

Here is the table:

```
SubjectID    TestDate         TestResult
01           05/01/2010       65
02           06/02/2011       .85
03           07/03/2012       .95
04           08/04/2013       .75
```

If the values in the column TestResult are between .65 and 1, I would like to multiply them by 100; otherwise I would like to keep the integer values from 65 to 100.

I've attempted the following, but I just get null values for the values between .65 and 1:

```
SELECT SubjectID, TestDate
         CASE WHEN TestResult  BETWEEN .65 AND 1 THEN TestResult *100
              WHEN TestResult BETWEEN 65 AND 100 THEN TestResult

         END AS TestResult
FROM     Table1
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the `TestResult` column?

Comment: The datatype of TestResult is Float

Comment: If it was float it should be 0.65. if your data looks like it does in your post, it's a varchar field.

Comment: [Not able to replicate](https://rextester.com/LFLTQI75867)

Comment: I found an error in my code. It's good now.

Comment: what was that error

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with your query, except for a comma.

Comment: I don't think you can use between with integer values in a conditional statement like this.  I think you have to use ">","<", and ">=', and "<=".

Answer (score 0):

Does this more general version work?

```
SELECT SubjectID, TestDate,
       (CASE WHEN TestResult <= 1.0 THEN TestResult * 100
             WHEN TestResult < 100 THEN TestResult
        END) AS new_TestResult
FROM  Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `<`,`>`,`<=`, and `>=` instad of `BETWEEN` might be more straightforward. It also may be necessary to convert `TestResult` to decimal depending on its type.

```
 SELECT SubjectID, TestDate,
     CASE WHEN CONVERT(decimal,TestResult) > .65 AND CONVERT(decimal,TestResult) < 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal,TestResult) * 100
          WHEN CONVERT(decimal,TestResult) >=  1 THEN TestResult
     END AS TestResult
 FROM     Table1
```